# Error while using Hmisc package : (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double'

Tags: r, correlation, hmisc

I want to find pearson correlation. #cols is 100 and #rows is 300. I am using the following commands:

```
library(Hmisc)

x <- (read.csv("input.csv",header=TRUE))
y <- rcorr(as.matrix(as.numeric(x)), type="pearson")

Error in as.matrix(as.numeric(x)) : 
  (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double'
```

I have tried all combination to solve this error. Can anyone help me in this?

Some of my data is

```
                        A   B    C    D    E    F 
        221974_at      9.01 8.85 9.27 9.57 9.65 8.83 
        216850_at      6.91 6.79 6.8 7.34 6.78 7.16 
        215559_at      7.79 6.42 7.11 5.6 6.55 5.88 
        1570255_s_at   5.43 6.55 4.76 6.34 5.42 6.3 
        1554245_x_at   5.85 6.45 5.91 6.23 7.03 6.65 
        1553607_at     5.44 5.44 4.84 3.7 3.24 5.39 
        244766_at      8.08 8.44 8.44 8.81 8.36 8.45
```

I am also giving this header in input file.

Comment: Can you provide some data to reproduce the issue ?  It would make it easier to troubleshoot.

Comment: Here is some data
                         A  B C D E F 
221974_at 9.01 8.85 9.27 9.57 9.65 8.83 
216850_at 6.91 6.79 6.8 7.34 6.78 7.16 
215559_at 7.79 6.42 7.11 5.6 6.55 5.88 
1570255_s_at 5.43 6.55 4.76 6.34 5.42 6.3 
1554245_x_at 5.85 6.45 5.91 6.23 7.03 6.65 
1553607_at 5.44 5.44 4.84 3.7 3.24 5.39 
244766_at 8.08 8.44 8.44 8.81 8.36 8.45 
215133_s_at 8.8 7.23 6.34 8.84 8.03 8.89 
241953_at 4.25 4.07 3.96 3.74 4.72 3.19 
223098_s_at 8.56 8.69 8.63 8.71 8.71 8.88 
212390_at 8.9 8.41 8.69 9.03 9 9.2 
214456_x_at 12.4 8.59 10.46 9.89 10.7 7.45 
201308_s_at 7.02 7.43 8.03 7.27 6.65 6.79

Comment: You should put the data in the original post.  If you use `dput(your_dataframe)` (on a small enough data set to produce the problem) that would help.

Comment: I used `dput` but it is still giving me same error.

Comment: what does `str(x)` look like?

Comment: @Akriti `dput` was just to get a sample of input data so those trying to help you could debug with data that reproduces the problem.  Given your data is in `x`, you would include the results of `dput(x)` in your post.  It would be best to have `x` be a small sample that reproduces the issue.